# Navigation axis with Google Charts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-visualization

In short I am doing a simple bar chart, represent the company profit and expenses, etc.. for each year,

Html code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> 
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Javascript

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Yeat','Sales in Millions'],
      ['2010', 10],
      ['2011', 14],
      ['2012', 13],
      ['2014', 18],
      ['2015', 22],
      ['2016', 24],
      ['2017', 21],
      ['2018', 26],
      ['2019', 30],
      ['2020', 40]
    ]);

    var options = {
      width: 600,
      height: 400,
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  }
```

Assume that I have many years from 2000 to 2021, what I want to make a scrollable timeline in the H-axis like this one, how I can achieve this

Note: the example above made with vue-google-chart, don't worry just feel free to update the google parameter or create new example for only google chart if you want to

[image]

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question as well or the question will loose its value if codesanbox closes

Comment: you can use google's [ChartRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter)...